# SEDE for the number of votes cast in the last seven days

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer

The title is self explanatory.

I am trying to check the status for [Vote early, vote often](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/vote-early-vote-often) hat.

Any way around using SEDE? Or maybe without using it?

Note that I am not asking for the votes cast in the current week (which is already shown on the profile page). What I want is the number of votes cast in the last (consecutive) 7 days.

Comment: It's right on your profile... All the way at the bottom, on the right.

Comment: @Shog9 I am not referring to that. Read "Note" in my question above.

Comment: Ah. Then go to the Votes tab in your profile and count back 7 days.

Comment: There's no way to automate that? A SEDE query maybe?

Comment: Votes are anonymous and that is also true for SEDE.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but you can't generally query *anything* "in the last seven days" on SEDE, except [early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq). *e.g.* there'd be a five-day-ish gap right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment above, votes are anonymous, and there is no way to retrieve them, not even via SEDE.